# Jasper Report Desginer does not show static text or text field

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Originally my report is created in v5.2.0. My report also uses resource bundles file. When open in eclipse using ireport designer plugin v 5.2.0, it can show all - static text and text field. [image]

But when I am using ireport designer v5.1.0. It shows nothing. like  [image]

Do I need to configure something in iReport Designer?? Am I missing something??

Comment: Each version of iReport is designed to use the corresponding version of the JasperReports library, and they are not backwards-compatible.

Comment: GenericJohn, that is not correct. iReport IS backwards compatible, you can select specifically for which library version you want to export a report.

At least, your answer has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this happen because of the size of the static text box in relation to the font size.  If the Font size is too large, it will cause the text to wrap to the next line and out of the frame.  I am guessing that different versions of iReport have different thresholds before the wrapping occurs.

What I ended up doing to verify this was to make the box bigger until the text appeared.  Then I played with the Font size until it would fit in the size box I needed.

Comment: I can confirm this! When the fontsize is bigger than the text-box it appears that the text vanished.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about the display problem. When the report is generated all text should be shown. If not set the options "Print when detail overflows" and "Stretch with overflow". The latter option is only available within dynamic text fields.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my XML formatter "helpfully" put a new line inside my CDATA['s!!